# Django REST TestCase: How to retrieve a response queryset that wasn't assigned to an attribute?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset, django-testing

For a view that extends a generic `ListAPIView` and returns a queryset by simply assigning a collection to the View `queryset` attribute, like so:

```
class MyView(ListAPIView):
   queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
```

How can the queryset be retrieved in the TestCase for this view?

```
def test_my_view(self):
    request = self.factory.get('my/url') # self.factory was set in the setUp method
    response = MyView.as_view()(request)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    # I'd like to now test the query set, something like
    # self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.queryset, [])
```

I've found that on querysets that are assigned to an attribute, the way to retrieve the queryset is this:

```
response.context['queryset_attribute_name']
```

But I'd like my view to act like a simple REST endpoint for the front end and not add the attribute name to it.

This seems like such a simple thing to do, but I'm new to Django and just can't figure out how to do it and already wasted way too much time searching for it...

Comment: What do you want to test on the QuerySet? Normally you would want to test that your rendered response (the JSON) contains the objects you expect. E.g. `self.assertEqual(0, len(response.json()))` if the response is returning a list of serialised objects as is the case for the `ListAPIView`. You don't need to actually have the `Queryset` (you would be testing very little, since you already know that you're setting the `Queryset` to all your `MyModel` objects).

Comment: Actually, if you're using `django-rest-framework`, your response has the properties `data` and `content`. `response.data` should be a python list in case of a list view, `response.content` is the the JSON string.

Comment: Yes, perfect! response.data was what I was looking for, thank you!
If you post it as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to capture the actual `QuerySet` that was used for the response and write a test for it, you should look at the response itself. Since you're writing an API I assume you want to assert that the JSON contains the correct data.

For the django-rest-framework, a `Response` object has two attributes: `response.data` is the python serialised data used to render the JSON, while `response.content` is the JSON itself.

So, if your `MyModel` doesn't have any objects yet, you could test:

```
self.assertEqual(0, len(response.data))
```

or

```
self.assertEqual("[]", response.content)
```